# Undefined method send_data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting undefined method `send_data` when creating multiple tabs in spreadsheet. I am not able to understand what data should be sent using this `send_Data` method.

Here is my error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `send_data' for #<Class:0x007f911933cc58>):

book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
      sheet1 = book.create_worksheet :name => 'Sheet1'
      sheet2 = book.create_worksheet :name => 'Sheet2'
      sheet1.row(0).push "some content in Column1"
       spreadsheet = StringIO.new

      book.write spreadsheet
       file = "#{Rails.root}/public/brand_store/Excelsheet"

       send_data spreadsheet.string, :filename => "#{file}", :type =>  "application/vnd.ms-excel"
```

Comment: perhaps there is no `send_data` method?

Comment: yeah i have not created send_data method actually no idea what to send in send_data method ..I need a sample how to send data using send_data method

Comment: send_data is a Rails [helper method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html). It would appear that you're trying to display an Excel spreadsheet in the browser, but your code is in the model, where helper methods aren't allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`send_data` is used to render binary data format to browser, it is not accesible in `rails model` [Here](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_data) is the official documentation for the `send_data` method.

In your case, I guess you wrote your Excel file genration `code` in `model`, So just return the `Spreadsheet` object and write code in controller for render your excel file or you can save it into temp file and render it from `controller` by providing that file path in `send_data` method.

Hope this will help.